# Semiconductors : Zener Diode

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

I was wondering how a large current flows after a small change in the zener breakdown voltage. I know why it happens at the zener voltage, but my book says that even after insignificant change in the voltage, a large current is observed. I don't know this. Should it be like, more bonds can be broken even by a smallest change in the zener voltage? Clear.

Comment: No bonds are broken, so it would seem that your mental model is leading you down the wrong way.

Comment: then the correct explanation?

Comment: Where in, say, the Wikipedia entry do you stop following the explanation? Do you understand tunneling and avalanche breakdown?

Comment: Yes, i do! but that's not my answer..... Can you please show me something good!

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear exactly what about the standard explanations, for example in the Wikii articles on zener breakdown and avalanche breakdown, you don't understand.